# How can you express "as long as you want"?

Tags: translation, sentence

I want to tell my friend that he can stay at my house as long as he wants.

I was thinking:

> 泊まるのは何ヶ日でもいいです。

or

> 泊まりたい程泊まってもいいです。

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of those work with a little fixing.

何日でも泊まってもいい

泊まりたいだけ泊まってもいい

or

好きなだけ泊まってもいい

Hell, throw it all together and you can sound like a super welcoming friend lol.

> 何日でも好きなだけ泊まってくれ！

Answer (score 4):

To choose between the two sentences, the first one is much better by the native standards.
However, 「何ヶ日」 sounds very awkward.  「[何日]{なんにち}」 is the correct word.  You can also say 「[何ヶ月]{なんかげつ}」 if you guys are talking long-term, but not 「何ヶ日」, which is probably why I, a native speaker, do not know how to read it.

Your second sentence is incorrect because of the use of 「[程]{ほど}」.  Replace it with 「だけ」 and you will have a correct sentence.

Comment: Would 存分に be awkward here?

Comment: @ssb Yeah I think you could say 思う存分泊まっていくがよい！うわははは to sound like 時代劇